# Is this a possible memory leak?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, uinavigationcontroller

```
-(IBAction) btnLoginPressed{

    Login *loginOverView = [[Login alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:loginOverView animated:YES];
    [loginOverView release];
}
```

loginOverView will never get released?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think it will never get released?

You have done the right thing by balancing the init with a release.

(in the second line the navigationController does retain login but it will release it itself when it is necessary)

Comment: Agreed. The pushViewController:animated: method is responsible for retaining/releasing the reference you're passing to it. You only have to worry about what you are allocating.

Answer (score 0):

You have released the object which you have taken ownership of through `alloc` or `new`. So according to the Memory Management guidelines you must `release` it. So you have done the right thing.